# Retrieve and update field of a model on views and display updated field in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a view that retrieves the field(user's score) that is declared in a model, where I will also update the field(user's score) after a simple if-else statement, then display the field in template.

But now, in the template's text area, where I put the result, it is now only showing **userScore: userScore object (1), False**, instead of the value of the user's score.

So, how can I retrieve the score of the user from the model and update the field in views?

**morse_logs/game1.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <title>GAME 1</title>
    <h1>GAME 1</h1>
    <h2>1 + 1 = ?</h2>
    <form action="" method="get" >
        <input type="number" id="ans1" name="ans1"/><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="game1Answer">Submit</button><br><br>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='a2' > {{currentS}} </textarea>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**morse_logs/views.py**

```
@login_required()
def game1(request):

    if request.user and not request.user.is_anonymous:
        user = request.user
    #else:
        #Throw some raised exception here as the user is not valid...

    """The Game 1 page"""
    def verifyGame1(val1):
        user_score = userScore.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        if val1 == 2:
            #user's score declared in model increase 5points
            #display correct and 5 points added to user
            user_score.score += 5
            #user_score = str(user_score)
            user_score.save()
            return user_score
        else:
            #user's score declared in model has no point
            #display incorrect and 1 point added to user
            #user_score = str(user_score)
            return user_score

    ans1 = request.GET.get('ans1', '')
    cScore = verifyGame1(ans1)

    return render(request, 'morse_logs/game1.html', {'currentS': cScore})
```

**users/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class userScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `get_or_create` returns a tuple, the first value is the object and the second value is `True` if the object is created. So change the line in your view to:

```
user_score, created = userScore.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

Then `userScore` is a model, the score is stored in the `score` field. To show the value in your template, either

put this in your template:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='a2' > {{currentS.score}} </textarea>
```

or pass the score value from your view to your template:

```
return render(request, 'morse_logs/game1.html', {'currentS': cScore.score})
```

Finally: Make sure you are passing an integer as val1 to your `verifyGame1` function, the `<input>` in html returns a string. So something like `cScore = verifyGame1(int(ans1))`.

Comment: I have changed it to the first approach, but now nothing is shown in the textarea, and is there anything incorrect for how I update the score, because the score did not get updated.

Comment: and if i use second approach, it prompts the error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'score'

Comment: @Din Sorry, I overlooked something in your code. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, now i can retrieve the score in the textarea, but the score won't be updated after entering the correct answer.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You need to make sure you pass an integer to your function. 2 is not '2'